# Get subscriber's name from SSRS database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, encryption, reporting-services

what I am trying to do is creating a report about failed subscriptions in MS SQL Server Report Server (SSRS). What I have done so far is the following SQL statement:

```
USE ReportServer
GO

WITH SubscriptionsCTE AS
(
   SELECT
      c.[Name],
      c.[Path],
      s.[Description],
      s.LastStatus,
      s.LastRunTime,
      CONVERT(xml, s.ExtensionSettings) AS ExtensionSettings,
      s.DeliveryExtension
   FROM
      dbo.Subscriptions s
      INNER JOIN dbo.[Catalog] c ON c.ItemID = s.Report_OID
   WHERE
      s.LastStatus LIKE 'Failure%'
)
SELECT
   [Name],
   [Path],
   [Description],
   LastStatus,
   LastRuntime,
   CASE
      WHEN DeliveryExtension = 'Report Server FileShare' THEN (SELECT e.c.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') FROM ExtensionSettings.nodes('ParameterValues/ParameterValue') e(c) WHERE e.c.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'USERNAME')
      WHEN DeliveryExtension = 'Report Server Email' THEN (SELECT e.c.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') FROM ExtensionSettings.nodes('ParameterValues/ParameterValue') e(c) WHERE e.c.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'TO')
      ELSE NULL
   END AS Subscriber
FROM
   SubscriptionsCTE
```

The problem is that the field Subscriber is encrypted for FileShare subscriptions. I understand that it is for the password... but for the user name? As an administrator I have access to the subscriptions via the GUI, but it is a pain to look into every report's admin panel to find out the user name.

I did something like

```
CASE WHEN Subscriber = '(some encrypted string)' THEN 'User 1'
   WHEN Subscriber = '(some other encrypted string)' THEN 'User 2'
   (etc.)
   ELSE NULL
END AS Subscriber
```

But obviously, it is not encrypted in the same way in every record, so 'User 1' has a different encrypted string in every subscription.

Is there any way to decrypt these strings? I have the .snk file from the Report Server certificates backup (and know the password for it). Does this help?

Thanks for helping...

Best wishes
Michael

Comment: For file share delivery extensions, the username you're accessing is the user account for sending the file to the specified share -- not necessarily subscribers.  I would imagine that most of the time this would be a service account of some sort.  Also, file share downloads are accessible by anyone who has access to the share so not sure how useful this information would be here.

Comment: Anthony, yes you are right, "Subscribers" is definitely not the right word. And yes, it some service account. I must not talk about the "usefulness" of this information here, but for me it is...